# Change DeliveryMode Of Messages

Tags: jms, kaazing

Can i change the DeliveryMode to NON-PERSISTENT of message sent from Kaazing jms edition using jmsclient.js to Message Broker, as by default it is taking Persistent only everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same using jmsclient.js predefined function 
    producer.send(txt message, DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, INT, LONG, CALLBACK).